# R leaflet: addPolygons by group

Tags: r, leaflet

I am not able to make the group variable work in leaflet to create polygons for each group.

My data:

```
data <- data.frame(group = c("p_pladser.1", "p_pladser.1", "p_pladser.2","p_pladser.2", "p_pladser.3", "p_pladser.3", "p_pladser.4", "p_pladser.4","p_pladser.6", "p_pladser.6", "p_pladser.6"), lat = c(55.67179, 55.67171, 55.67143, 55.67135, 55.67110, 55.67099, 55.67173, 55.67158, 55.67155, 55.67154, 55.67145), long = c(12.55825, 12.55853, 12.55956, 12.55984, 12.56041, 12.56082, 12.55819, 12.55873, 12.55913, 12.55914, 12.55946))
```

What I have tried

```
leaflet(data) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(lat = ~ lat, lng = ~ long, group = ~ group)
```

This results in:

[image]

What I need is the parking spaces to be individually connected, underneath done with the same data in ggplot2.

```
ggplot() + 
geom_line(data=data, aes(lat, long, group=group)) +
theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

Edit: Sample data for creating polygons by group.

```
df <- data.frame(group = c(9,9,9,9,3,3,4,10,4,4,6,6,9,9,6,7,8,6,6,6,4,10,10,10,10,5,5,5,5,6,2,6,8,10,4,1,1,8,2,2,8,1,1,2,3,3,1,2,3,5,5,7,7,7,7,7), lat = c(12.51324264,12.513305365,12.513460965,12.513471705,12.51323028,12.51343869,12.51002744,12.50998803,12.50981405,12.50976721,12.511631235,12.513047085,12.513872565,12.51284178,12.512897255,12.51491698,12.51098456,12.51271646,12.512567055,12.51193457,12.510672405,12.509586335,12.509513235,12.509228595,12.51019304,12.514326785,12.51430267,12.51431847,12.514476435,12.512163885,12.51235039,12.51238198,12.51063921,12.51044102,12.510237215,12.510051915,12.51031317,12.511275515,12.51133816,12.51112378,12.51150496,12.50974082,12.51063222,12.51169496,12.512893665,12.51391899,12.510612445,12.51168118,12.5127838,12.5139199,12.515012135,12.51503213,12.515610885,12.515487105,12.515415995,12.51546271), long = c(55.662148595,55.66274813,55.662200085,55.662681285,55.6618097,55.66187776,55.66261815,55.66273954,55.66191013,55.66203335,55.66224483,55.66231779,55.662361495,55.662510495,55.662309905,55.66241728,55.66220386,55.662301165,55.6622937,55.662261925,55.66218702,55.663355645,55.663463555,55.66335952,55.663351875,55.661814145,55.66214884,55.661928915,55.662022445,55.66189588,55.66176534,55.662082195,55.66289834,55.663009465,55.66231188,55.661666315,55.66180155,55.662641355,55.661861295,55.661826095,55.662688875,55.66121794,55.66126692,55.66132434,55.661389205,55.66144555,55.66141339,55.661468365,55.661532485,55.66159399,55.66165429,55.661505195,55.662096835,55.6617923,55.662226165,55.661944765))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you need to turn your coordinates into a `SpatialLines` object and use `addPolylines`.

Below I've converted the data into a `SpatialLines` object, its important to have the columns appearing as long and then lat.

Essentially, the data is split by group, turned into a matrix of the long/lat and then converted into a Line, which is pushed into an ID'd Lines object. Which is all wrapped up into SpatialLines.

## Lines

```
library(leaflet)
library(sp)

# data
data <- data.frame(group = c("p_pladser.1", "p_pladser.1", "p_pladser.2","p_pladser.2", "p_pladser.3", "p_pladser.3", "p_pladser.4", "p_pladser.4","p_pladser.6", "p_pladser.6", "p_pladser.6"), lat = c(55.67179, 55.67171, 55.67143, 55.67135, 55.67110, 55.67099, 55.67173, 55.67158, 55.67155, 55.67154, 55.67145), long = c(12.55825, 12.55853, 12.55956, 12.55984, 12.56041, 12.56082, 12.55819, 12.55873, 12.55913, 12.55914, 12.55946))

# turn into SpatialLines
split_data = lapply(unique(data$group), function(x) {
  df = as.matrix(data[data$group == x, c("long", "lat")])
  lns = Lines(Line(df), ID = x)
  return(lns)
})

data_lines = SpatialLines(split_data)

leaflet(data_lines) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolylines()
```

[image]

---

## Polygons

if you want to use polygons then you will create a `SpatialPolygons` object, which is done in much the same way lines are done.

Expect to see some warning messages as there are not more than four sets of coordinates in the polygons, it will recycle the first pair until it reaches four.

```
split_data_poly = lapply(unique(data$group), function(x) {
  df = as.matrix(data[data$group == x, c("long", "lat")])
  polys = Polygons(list(Polygon(df)), ID = x)
  return(polys)
})

data_polys = SpatialPolygons(split_data_poly)

leaflet(data_polys) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons()
```

---

## Unordered Polygon & Colour

This isn't as simple, and is becomes more complicated the more points there are. 
The real 'easy' solution would be to get the data from a source where it is appropriately ordered. 
A quick alternative is to use convex hull `chull`. This IS NOT guaranteed to maintain shape.

Adding colour is easier, you can turn the `SpatialPolygon` into a `SpatialPolygonDataFrame` which has meta information on the group and its colour.

The example below contains the colour in the `SpatialPolygonDataFrame` as a column, this is just alternating between red and blue in this example.

```
data <- data.frame(group = c(9,9,9,9,3,3,4,10,4,4,6,6,9,9,6,7,8,6,6,6,4,10,10,10,10,5,5,5,5,6,2,6,8,10,4,1,1,8,2,2,8,1,1,2,3,3,1,2,3,5,5,7,7,7,7,7), lat = c(12.51324264,12.513305365,12.513460965,12.513471705,12.51323028,12.51343869,12.51002744,12.50998803,12.50981405,12.50976721,12.511631235,12.513047085,12.513872565,12.51284178,12.512897255,12.51491698,12.51098456,12.51271646,12.512567055,12.51193457,12.510672405,12.509586335,12.509513235,12.509228595,12.51019304,12.514326785,12.51430267,12.51431847,12.514476435,12.512163885,12.51235039,12.51238198,12.51063921,12.51044102,12.510237215,12.510051915,12.51031317,12.511275515,12.51133816,12.51112378,12.51150496,12.50974082,12.51063222,12.51169496,12.512893665,12.51391899,12.510612445,12.51168118,12.5127838,12.5139199,12.515012135,12.51503213,12.515610885,12.515487105,12.515415995,12.51546271), long = c(55.662148595,55.66274813,55.662200085,55.662681285,55.6618097,55.66187776,55.66261815,55.66273954,55.66191013,55.66203335,55.66224483,55.66231779,55.662361495,55.662510495,55.662309905,55.66241728,55.66220386,55.662301165,55.6622937,55.662261925,55.66218702,55.663355645,55.663463555,55.66335952,55.663351875,55.661814145,55.66214884,55.661928915,55.662022445,55.66189588,55.66176534,55.662082195,55.66289834,55.663009465,55.66231188,55.661666315,55.66180155,55.662641355,55.661861295,55.661826095,55.662688875,55.66121794,55.66126692,55.66132434,55.661389205,55.66144555,55.66141339,55.661468365,55.661532485,55.66159399,55.66165429,55.661505195,55.662096835,55.6617923,55.662226165,55.661944765))

split_data_poly = lapply(unique(data$group), function(x) {
  df = as.matrix(data[data$group == x, c("long", "lat")])
  ch = chull(df) # remove me if not wanted
  df = df[ch, ] # remove me if not wanted
  polys = Polygons(list(Polygon(df)), ID = x)
  return(polys)
  return(df)
})

data_polys = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SpatialPolygons(split_data_poly),
                                      data.frame(group = 1:10, colour = c("red", "blue")))

leaflet(data_polys) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(color = ~colour)
```

Comment: Thanks, this will solve the problem if they are all lines, but when there are more than two points, I would like leaflet to draw polygons. Is this possible?

Comment: Sure it is, you just need to create polygons instead of lines. - see above

Comment: Last question then you will get it. When adding polygons leaflet does not draw polygons but rather randombly connect the points. Is there a way to solve that too?

Comment: Provide example data and I will

Comment: Thanks, I have added it now. If it easy easy to add colors by group, I would like to see that also.

Comment: Your data is more problematic than you may realise, you should seek data that comes ordered. Otherwise you may need to create a seperate question as its not in the scope of this questions original intent (which I've addressed). Colouring has been added. That's where I'm leaving it.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I have attempted to award you the bounty, but it says that I cannot do it till in 17 hours.... When the time has passed, I will make sure you get the 50 points.